# How can I output an identity matrix in progressiveMauve?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I'm just getting started with the Mauve aligner and I'm finding the documentation a bit lacking. I'm using the `progressiveMauve` tool from the command line and would like to output an identity matrix file. The set of output files it generates by default for `progressiveMauve --output=outfile` are `outfile`, `outfile.backbone` and `output.bbcols`.

The [documentation](http://darlinglab.org/mauve/user-guide/progressivemauve.html) for the tool lists an `--input-id-matrix` option but this doesn't seem to have any effect. The [documentation page for output files](http://darlinglab.org/mauve/user-guide/files.html) does describe an identity matrix file but doesn't say anything about how to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

mauve documentation have a similar command but the usage is `--id-matrix=<file>`. So very similar to the progressivemauve command (just doesn't include --input). Try it and see if it works.

I think it's a bug for sure as several other people on biostar have complained.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed seems that the `--input-id-matrix` option doesn't work as expected, as [Amar has pointed out](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/346/123).

I tried the following command:

```
./progressiveMauve genome1.fasta genome2.fasta genome3.fasta --output=test > test.log
```

And saw the following bits in `test.log` (truncated):

```
[...]
Genome conservation distance matrix:
0       0.0767545       0.187454
0.0767545       0       0.193385
0.187454        0.193385        0

[...]
genome content distance matrix:
0       0.0767545       0.187454
0.0767545       0       0.193385
0.187454        0.193385        0

bp distance matrix:
0.9     0.0125  0.075
0.0125  0.9     0.0375
0.075   0.0375  0.9
[...]
```

Could any of those three tables contain the information you are looking for?

p.s. as an aside, if you are looking into a way to obtain a whole genome similarity matrix you might want to look into [mash](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-0997-x) or [sourmash](https://sourmash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).